# How to define morphisms involved with empty sets

Tags: category-theory

I am beginning to learn something about categories and I have a little question.

In the category theory, how to define Mor(A, B) if A or/and B is/are empty set(s)?  And why they are defined those ways?

Comment: If $A = \emptyset$ there is only one possible function $f: \emptyset \to B$, for any given set $B$, namely, the "empty function" whose graph is: $\emptyset \times B = \emptyset$. As stated below, it is not possible to define $f: A \to \emptyset$ when $A \neq \emptyset$, as if there exists $a \in A$, $f(a)$ must be an element of $B$, and when $B = \emptyset$ there are no such elements.

Comment: @DavidWheeler I can understand Mor(A, $\emptyset$)=$\emptyset$ now. But how to see Mor($\emptyset$, B) only contains one element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the category of sets, $\operatorname{Mor}(\emptyset,A)$ has one element for any $A$, and $\operatorname{Mor}(A,\emptyset)$ has zero elements for any nonempty $A$.

This is because the definition of a function allows for an empty set of ordered pairs.

In set theory, a function is defined as a certain subset of the product of the domain and codomain.  $\emptyset \times B = \emptyset$.  Does $\emptyset \subset \emptyset$ have the properties needed to be a function?  We need that $\forall a \in \emptyset \exists b \in B$ such that $(a,b) \in \emptyset$.  This is satisfied because there are no $a \in \emptyset$, so the universal quantifier is automatically true.  We also need that if $(a,b_1) \in \emptyset$ and $(a,b_2) \in \emptyset$ then $b_1 = b_2$.  This is also vacuously satisfied.  So $\emptyset$ is a function from $\emptyset \to B$.

This is also convenient because it gives the category of sets an initial object:  the empty set.  In fact, we could conceive of different formal definitions of a function which behave the same for nonempty domains and codomains, but has some different behaviour for empty domains or codomains.  These other definitions might be fine for most purposes, but they would make the category of sets a less nice category.  So this behaviour can be seen as confirmation that our definition of a function is "correct".

Comment: Interestingly, this is also why $n^0=1$, and $0^n=0$ except for $0^0=1$

Comment: Your answer and comment can both be viewed as continuity of the hom-functor in its first argument.

Comment: @StevenGubkin Can you make it more clear? I cannot understand what do you mean by "allows for an empty set of ordered pairs".

Comment: @Akatsuki I added some clarification.

Comment: @StevenGubkin Thanks.